# Sales order email template magento2

Tags: magento2

Can any one help me to edit the email template design in magento2
Please find the screen shots below.

by default iam getting email like this  below screenshot

[image]

i want to modify the like below screenshot

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCrFL.]png

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by add new `Theme` and overwrite the `Magento_Sales` with the file template in `templates/email/items.phtml`